# What are "legacy brands"?

Tags: meaning

Does the phrase "Legacy brands" just mean "companies that are inherited from generation to generation" or there is another particular meaning?

[Here is the context:](http://blog.statuspage.io/customer-service-email) The writer is wanting to know what other companies use for email responses - do they use a auto-reply or a personal reply?

> The first thing to do was decide which companies to send these out to. This was probably the most subjective part of the experiment. One hundred companies seems like a lot until you start considering the many thousands of potential companies to pick from.
>
> I knew we wanted a lot of SaaS companies and a good mix of technology startups. I also wanted a range of small, medium, and large sized organizations. **But just for good measure, some non-tech and legacy brands could be interesting.** A lot these companies have been thinking about customer service for generations. I added a few hardware companies, some airlines.

Wikipedia showed this result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brand_legacy But I don't think it's appliable to my case.

Comment: I did the following Google search (including quotes): "legacy brand" + meaning.  It brought up this very good article from Entrepreneur magazine: http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/232432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computing, ***[Legacy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/legacy)*** implies a different meaning

> Denoting or relating to software or hardware that has been superseded but is difficult to replace because of its wide use.

[[ODO](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/148/153448)]

Therefore, the author of the linked blogpost had decided to include even brands that have been replaced by newer brands but still continue to be used widely. I read the article and I couldn't make out what legacy brands did the author choose for his experiment.

To make it clear, Windows XP could be considered a ***legacy brand*** owing to its widespread use even after the launch of subsequent versions (like Windows 8 or  Windows 10)

On the other hand, ***brand legacy*** is a different entity. It's the popularity , trust and impact created by a brand on the consumers. Let's consider **[Apple Inc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.)**. Apple is not a ***legacy brand*** (not superseded by competitors or other vendors, yet) but their ***brand legacy*** (sometimes also known as "brand value" ) is unparalleled in the entire hardware and software industries combined.

Comment: @AlinaSaidova - I have added more examples for your understanding.

Comment: He's probably thinking of General Mills, Proctor & Gamble, DuPont, etc etc. so-called "Household names".